# SQL query to select percentage of total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL table stores that has the following columns in a table:

```
Storeid, NumEmployees
1       125 
2       154
3       10 
4       698
5       54  
6       98
7       87
8       100
9       58
10      897
```

Can someone help me with the SQL query to produce the top stores(storeID) that has 30% of the total emplyees(NumEmployees)?

Comment: I have tried select SUM(numemploees).. Found 30% then select top from that sum.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want. Do you want the rows, starting at storeid 1 and going until you get a total of 30%? Which would give you stores 1,2,3,4.    Or do you want the rows, start at the store with the most employees and working down until you have 30 %? Which would just give you store 10? Or allthe stores that have 30% or more?  Which would give you 4 and 10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT storeid, 
                numemployees, 
                ( numemployees * 100 ) / SUM(numemployees) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) 
                AS 
                percentofstores 
         FROM   stores) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  percentofstores >= 30 
ORDER BY numemployees desc
```

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be2fa/1)

Alternative that doesn't use SUM/OVER

```
SELECT s.storeid, s.numemployees 
FROM   (SELECT SUM(numemployees) AS [tots] 
        FROM   stores) AS t, 
       stores s 
WHERE  CAST(numemployees AS DECIMAL(15, 5)) / tots >= .3 
ORDER BY s.numemployees desc
```

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be2fa/14)

Note that in the second version I decided not to multiply by 100  before dividing. This requires a cast to decimal otherwise it would be implicitly converted to a int resulting in no records returned

Also I'm not completely clear that you want this, but you can add `TOP 1` to both queries and it will limit the results to just the one with the greatest # of stores with more than 30%

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments it sounds to paraphrase [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047048/sql-query-to-select-percentage-of-total/10047147#comment12855455_10047048)

> You want the rows, starting at the store with the most employees and working down until you have at least 30 %

This is difficult because it requires a running percentage and its a bin packing problem however this does work. Note I've included two other test cases (where the percent exactly equals and its just over the top two combined)

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be2fa/28)

```
DECLARE @percent DECIMAL (20, 16) 

SET @percent = 0.3
--Other test values
--SET @percent = 0.6992547128452433
--SET @percent = 0.6992547128452434 

;WITH sums 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT s.storeid, 
                         s.numemployees, 
                         s.numemployees + Coalesce(SUM(s2.numemployees) OVER ( 
                                                   PARTITION 
                                                   BY 
                                                   s.numemployees), 0) 
                         runningsum 
         FROM   stores s 
                LEFT JOIN stores s2 
                  ON s.numemployees < s2.numemployees), 
     percents 
     AS (SELECT storeid, 
                numemployees, 
                runningsum, 
                CAST(runningsum AS DECIMAL(15, 5)) / tots.total 
                running_percent, 
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY runningsum, storeid ) rn 
         FROM   sums, 
                (SELECT SUM(numemployees) total 
                 FROM   stores) AS tots) 
SELECT p.storeID,
       p.numemployees,
       p.running_percent,
       p.running_percent,
       p.rn 
FROM   percents p 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(rn) rn 
                  FROM   percents 
                  WHERE  running_percent = @percent) exactpercent 

       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(rn) rn 
                   FROM   percents 
                   WHERE  running_percent <= @percent) underpercent 
         ON p.rn <= underpercent.rn 
             OR ( exactpercent.rn IS NULL 
                  AND p.rn <= underpercent.rn + 1 ) 
WHERE 
      underpercent.rn is not null or p.rn = 1
```

Comment: This doesnt work. inner query doesnt produce 0 fro percentofstores

Comment: I meant. The inner query produces 0 as the result for percentofstores for every record

Comment: hmm did you remove `* 100` before the division? If you did you'd need to cast to decimal

Comment: Perhaps if you created a SQL Fiddle of your own to demonstrate it would be eaiser to help?

Comment: I found the answer with a hack.

B =  30% of Sum(numemplyees(.


select top N Isrc from table order by numemployees desc

So i keep changing N until the sum = B