# Complex SQL SELECT to compute rating on a single column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

It may be considered a duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047048/sql-query-to-select-percentage-of-total), but my question is somehow more complicated. I have a MySQL table with these fields:

```
ip | product_id | visits
```

which shows how many times an ip has visited a product. I finally want to  generate a php array like this:

```
product_rating_for_ip = array(
  ip=>array(
    product_id=>rating, product_id=>rating, ...
  ),
  ip=>array(
    product_id=>rating, product_id=>rating, ...
  ),
  .
  .
  .
);
```

The rating is equal to the visits for a single product from some ip divided by MAX of all product visits by that ip .for example:

```
product_rating_for_ip = array(
  "78.125.15.92"=>array(
    1=>0.8,2=>0.2,3=>1.0
  ),
  "163.56.75.112"=>array(
    1=>0.1,2=>0.3,3=>0.5,8=>0.1,12=>1.0
  ),
  .
  .
  .
);
```

---

What I have done :

```
SELECT ip, id, visits, MAX(visits) FROM visit GROUP BY ip
```

---

I have performance considerations and I want to avoid SQL queries in nested loops. I think the above SQL query is incorrect as it does not show the expected results in action.

Comment: "The rating is equal to the visits for a single product from some ip divided by MAX of all product visits by that ip" Seems like it's `SUM` rather than `MAX`.

Comment: No it is MAX. the product with maximum visits is the basis for comparing and rating other products. the product with maximum visits has rating 1 of 1 and others have lower ratings from 0 to 1

Comment: And yet in your example no product has rating of 1.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment. thats typo, I will edit soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a subquery to calculate the sum, then do the calculation and put the values into a single comma-delimited column, which you can transform into an array in php:

```
select v.ip, group_concat(v.visits / iv.maxvisits) as ratings
from visit v join
     (SELECT ip, id, visits, max(visits) as maxvisits
      FROM visit
      GROUP BY ip
     ) iv
     on v.ip = iv.ip
group by v.ip;
```

EDIT:

Tables in SQL are inherently unordered and sorting in SQL is not stable (meaning the original order is not preserved).  You can specify an ordering in the `group_concat()` statement.  For instance, the following would order the results by `id`:

```
select v.ip, group_concat(v.visits / iv.maxvisits order by id) as ratings
from visit v join
     (SELECT ip, id, visits, max(visits) as maxvisits
      FROM visit
      GROUP BY ip
     ) iv
     on v.ip = iv.ip
group by v.ip;
```

And this would order by the highest rating first:

```
select v.ip, group_concat(v.visits / iv.maxvisits order by v.visits desc) as ratings
```

You can make the list more complex to include the `id` in it as well:

```
select v.ip,
      group_concat(concat(v.id, ':', v.visits / iv.maxvisits)) as ratings
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about generating the php array. I think that parts sucks too. would you please complete the answer to cover that part too?

Comment: I executed the query. It does not keep the order of values. Why?

Comment: I executed the query. It does not keep the order of values. Why? for example for a single ip it lists rating as:0.2500,0.5000,1.0000 for(4,1,2)

Comment: Thanks for your time and complete answer, but I can not extract the `id`s to push to the php array. would you please help me on this?

Comment: @Arash . . . My expertise is in SQL not php, so I'm not a good person to help with that aspect of the problem.